# symfony 4 application not updated in homestead/vagrant

Tags: php, symfony, virtualbox, homestead

I'm using Homestead for symfony 4 application.
Everthings work with symfony web server but,
homestead not recognized controller changes.

For example:
I create /test route in TestController but homestead

```
No route found for "GET /test"
```

I run `cache:clear` and remove `var` directory but nothing changed.
I'm using arch linux and homestead/virtualbox.

Can anyone give me a help about that?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you use the dev environment on homestead?

Comment: sf is dev in .env, I have warning `cache:clear` in vagrant `[WARNING] Failed to remove directory "/home/vagrant/code/sf18/var/cache/de~/ContainerJfG7x9X": .` and `[OK] Cache for the dev environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.`

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom vagrant script to build my VM but I have had this issue a few times - this is how I solved it:

**src/Kernel.php**

```
public function getCacheDir ()
{
    //return $this->getProjectDir().'/var/cache/'.$this->environment;
    return '/var/tmp/cache/' . $this->environment;
}

public function getLogDir ()
{
    //return $this->getProjectDir() . '/var/log';
    return '/var/tmp/log';
}
```

Also read https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-cache-dir

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem.
I recreated homestead box and left only one site in homestead.yaml file.
`sites:
    - map: sf18.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/sf18/public
      type: symfony4`

I believe it's related homestead.yaml and homestead-17 box.